# VBEのフォントサイズを変更できない

Tags: vba, font

VBEのフォントサイズを変更できません。フォント自体の変更や、その他の変更は可能です。
レジストリでFontHeightを変更してみましたが、VBEには反映しません。
環境は、Windows10(1703)、Excel2016です。
Word2016のVBEでも試しましたが、やはりフォントサイズだけが変更できません。
解決方法があればご教示いただきたく、よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 解決しました。「テキスト、アプリ、その他の項目サイズを変更する」を100%超にしていると大きくできないようです。200%なら12ポイントまで大きくできました。

Answer (score 1):

こちらを参考に…

[Office365のVBAでフォントサイズを変更できない - マイクロソフト コミュニティ](https://answers.microsoft.com/ja-jp/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-mso_win10-mso_2016/office365%E3%81%AEvba%E3%81%A7%E3%83%95%E3%82%A9/45aaf543-017d-444f-ad73-c968f0e24c6f)

私も同じ症状でしたが解決できました。

- ディスプレイの設定で「テキスト、アプリ、その他の項目サイズを変更する」を100％にいったん設定
- 再起動
- Excelを立ち上げ、VBEのフォントサイズ設定を修正
  　※ここで修正できなかった場合はほかの手段が必要かもしれません。
- ディスプレイの設定を元に戻す
- 再起動

Answer (score 0):

「テキスト、アプリ、その他の項目サイズを変更する」を100%超にしていると大きくできないようです。200%なら12ポイントまで大きくできました。

<sub>-- [Yutaさん](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/25776/yuta)の[コメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/38725/vbe%E3%81%AE%E3%83%95%E3%82%A9%E3%83%B3%E3%83%88%E3%82%B5%E3%82%A4%E3%82%BA%E3%82%92%E5%A4%89%E6%9B%B4%E3%81%A7%E3%81%8D%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84#comment39639_38725)より</sub>

Answer (score 0):

マルチディスプレイの場合、メインディスプレイの設定で「テキスト、アプリ、その他の項目サイズを変更する」を100% にするとフォントサイズが変えられるようです。